# Why is DigiNotar CA still in my Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: certificate-authority, firefox

I was just checking in my browser trusted certificates and surprisingly I saw that DigiNotar CA is there... as we know DigiNotar suffered a security breach back in 2011.

> DigiNotar was a Dutch certificate authority owned by VASCO Data
>   Security International, Inc.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X9wN.png) On September 3, 2011, after it had
>   become clear that a security breach had resulted in the fraudulent
>   issuing of certificates, the Dutch government took over operational
>   management of DigiNotar's systems.[2] That same month, the company was
>   declared bankrupt.[3]

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar

Why is that garbage CA even there?

[image]

Comment: You should probably specify which version under which OS. My browser does not have this CA in its trust store, for example.

Comment: 52.5.0 (64-bit) Debian 8.

Comment: ... notice that it says "... **because it is not trusted.**" ? If you click the "Details" tab, does it have the "`Explicitly Distrust DigiNotar Root CA`" like in my screenshot below?

Comment: If you are looking at the 'Servers' tab those are **blacklist** entries that explicitly DIStrust DigiNotar as opposed to merely omitting it from the trust list; see https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2011-35/ .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not really a cert, it's really more of an anti-cert, there to block DigiNotar even if some dumb user tries to click through the "`Add Exception...`" button.

The evidence is that it says "Could not verify this certificate **because it is not trusted**".

As pointed out by @JohnDeters, you can't revoke a self-signed root CA, so the only reason a root cert would not be trusted is if you open the "Details" tab and see that it's not actually a cert, but some weird Firefox object called `Builtin Object Token:Explicitly Distrust DigiNotar Root CA`.

[image: Firefox Builtin Object Token:Explicitly Distrust DigiNotar Root CA]

Comment: There's no CRL for trusted root CAs.  So each vendor has to deal with managing untrustworthy certificates in its own way.

Comment: Even if they explicitly distrust it - why do they still have to ship the certificate?

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing in my browser... I have posted a picture in my question...

Comment: @Arminius They don't ship a certificate. For me, there's nothing in the "Authorities" tab, just this "Explicitly Distrust" thing in the "Servers" tab. I'm guessing it's to block it even if someone tries to "Add Exception..." for a DigiNotar cert?

Comment: What troubles me is that this CA shows up in the "servers" tab alongside all other manually added exceptions, and there is no "Explicitly Distrust" mentioned in the Details tab. Other browsers list this CA clearly as "UNTRUSTED" in the CA list, not the servers list.

Comment: In Thunderbird, DigiNotar appears in Servers tab. If we click the entry there is a message "Could not verify this certificate because it has been revoked."